# The first time it connected just fine but now this happens

Tags: connection

```
2/14/19, 04:32:14.857 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/14/19, 04:32:14.858 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/14/19, 04:32:14.858 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
2/14/19, 04:32:14.858 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/14/19, 04:32:14.858 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/14/19, 04:32:14.859 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
2/14/19, 04:32:15.130 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
2/14/19, 04:32:15.140 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network 
2/14/19, 04:32:15.966 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop 
2/14/19, 04:32:26.662 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 7961FF5A7B77DFA46721ABE5B8DCF5FBBE26EF7B at 136.243.69.205:9001) 
2/14/19, 04:32:26.663 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
2/14/19, 04:32:26.663 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
2/14/19, 04:32:26.692 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
2/14/19, 04:32:26.692 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
```

Comment: From my experience, the means the network you are on blocks Tor - you can try bridges (obs4 is recommended) Otherwise, it could be a man in the middle attack Try removing Tor and reinstall. How to do that varies on platform. This probably won't help, but you never know

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear why Tor doesn't start in your case, but from your log, it could mean:

- Your [ISP (Internet Service Provider)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) blocks all Tor connections.

In your log, Tor said that it cannot setup a secure connection using [TLS (Transport Layer security)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security), which it's using for making Tor secure. If thats the case, you can try to avoid it by using bridges. Tor project website [provides a great explanation](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en) on how bridges work and how to use them.

- Your system clock is off sync.

Sometimes, Tor can't properly work if your system clock is off sync. You can find instructions online for your OS, just google someting along the lines of `How to synchronize time on *Insert the name of the OS you are using*`.

- Some program on your PC blocks Tor connection

While it's unlikely to happen, you may have a program that blocks Tor from working properly. For example, an antivirus. It was disscussed on Tor StackExchange already: [Tor browser conflicts with Malwarebytes antimalware](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14010/tor-browser-conflicts-with-malwarebytes-antimalware). Try to disable your antivirus and try again.