# Spying on TOR communications?

Tags: anonymity

Can the police, any spy agency or any government organizations track you on Tor and spy on what you're doing?

Or is the only way to do this hacking the computer or infecting it with a keylogger? If this is the only way, what's the likelihood of any agency doing that to you especially if they know about you and how can you protect yourself so no one hacks or keylogs your computer? 
Thanks

Comment: @NeverMine17 Not really a duplicate. This question asks about more powerful adversaries.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible (but usually difficult). Other than hacking the computer, there are some ways powerful adversaries could spy on you.

- Correlation attack: If you are unlucky, you might get an entry node/guard controlled by an adversary. Tor tries to prevent this by making entry nodes semi-permanent, so adversaries get only one (or a few) tries. 
  This does not necessarily compromise the whole circuit, but if you also get an exit node controlled by the same adversary, they will be able to correlate the traffic going into the entry node and coming out of the exit node.
- MITM (man-in-the-middle) attack: If you use HTTP, an adversary who is
  able to see the traffic coming out of the exit node will be able to
  see contents of the connection and modify them. They could also try
  to attack your browser if they know any vulnerabilities (most common
  are script exploits, most scripting is disabled in TBB at medium and
  high security setting). MITM would be much more difficult, but not
  impossible over HTTPS. This has happened with compromised CAs
  (certificate authorities) like DigiNotar, which have since been
  removed by Mozilla and TBB from trusted CAs. If you're concerned
  about this, check site certificates for anything suspicious.
- Compromised site: The site could be controlled by an adversary or
  working together with them.
- Identity correlation: Using any of these attacks to track your behavior and linking it to your real identity.

Usually at least two of these attacks would have to be combined to successfully deanonymize you.

> How can you protect yourself so no one hacks or keylogs your computer?

Most difficult question, depends on your threat model.

The basic thing you should do is to use good security practices (full disk encryption, sandboxing/hardening (not to be confused with hardened) Tor Browser) and don't use vulnerable or (up to your research and discretion) untrustworthy software.

Comment: Thanks. I have a software that runs certain files virtually (automatic) and asks me about the rest. Is that enough for sandboxing, or do I need something else? Is there a difference between sandboxing and hardening?  What software do you recommend for full disk encryption?

Comment: There is a possibility that they already gained access to my computer (physical access) but I've been checking TCPview and couldn't spot any suspicious remote address connections, they are mostly just Tor connections. Is there any other way to know if the computer is hacked/keylogged, or TCPview is enough and if there is nothing suspicious there it should be safe?

Comment: Since I don't know what software you're using, I can't tell. Sandboxing is software that contains the browser, hardening is making the browser less vulnerable. TBB is already hardened compared to Firefox. For full disk encryption, you should usually use the software provided by your OS. If you don't already, you might want to consider using a Linux distribution as your OS.

Comment: No way to tell if your computer is hacked from the computer itself. It would be possible for an adversary with access to your computer to simply hide their tracks.

Comment: I use Comodo Internet Security Sandboxing, is that enough? How can I harden the browser? So there is no way to know if a computer has been hacked, or if someone is keylogging or watching what I'm currently doing? I thought TCPview remote connections would at least tell if someone is currently keylogging or watching, wouldn't?

Comment: I don't know about Comodo or how their sandbox works. It might make TBB more secure, but it might also make it less secure in some way. It would be out of the scope of this question. You could ask a question about the security of TBB with Comodo sandbox, a similar question was asked on this site about [Malwarebytes](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/12628) so it shouldn't be off-topic. For the hardening, making custom changes to TBB configuration would probably be a bad idea. Tor Browser has good hardening features at higher security levels, the only thing that can improve that is a sandbox.

Comment: If you have reasonable suspicion your computer is compromised, only thing you can or should do is reinstall the OS. I can't recommend Windows, it isn't the best OS for security. It might even have government/agency backdoors. You could also try using another computer that you know is secure to watch any connections the (compromised?) computer makes and analyze them, but this is not always doable or a good solution.

Comment: I asked a question about Comodo sandbox separately. Is there any other way to know what connections the computer makes so I can analyze them and conclude if the computer is hacked/keylogged, except for TCPView, Comodo sandboxing and Malwarebytes scan?

Comment: Wireshark is a more comprehensive tool, but also more complex. You could use it both on your computer or if you decide to use another computer to analyze your connections. The problem with trying to do this on a computer you suspect is compromised is that the adversary could just infect that software as well and hide the information from you (or just prevent the software from intercepting it). As for Malwarebytes, you shouldn't be using it at all (see the linked question).

Comment: Thanks I downloaded Wireshark, how do I use it on a second computer to analyze my connections on the current computer though?